# Loading data, ListView and AsyncTask (need advice)

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

So I have to show a list. The data is retrieved from a database, as a JSON file...
What I would like is some comments about my code and eventually what I'm doing wrong (if I am). Or better ways to do this.

The list I retrieve can change with whatever is selected on the spinner.
The number of rows to show on the list is variable, so sometimes the list won't go to the bottom of the screen.

I've erased some of the useless code to the problem.

If anything is missing, tell me and i'll edit the code :)

```java
public class EcranFavoris extends Activity implements OnScrollListener, OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener
{
    /* ... */

    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner_adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    ListView listViewFavoris;

    /* This extends BaseAdapter */
    FavorisListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner_adapter;
    ArrayList<Profil> profil_array;

    /* ... */

    public static long currentId = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favoris_layout);

        /* ... */

        /* This contains the elements of my list. */
        profil_array = new ArrayList<Profil>();

        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Patientez...", "Chargement des favoris.", true);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        listViewFavoris = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.favoris_listView);
        adapter = new FavorisListAdapter(this, profil_array);
        listViewFavoris.setAdapter(adapter);
        listViewFavoris.setOnScrollListener(this);
        listViewFavoris.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        /* This is an AsyncTask i'm using for loading the data from the WebService. */
        new WebServiceWork().execute(profil_array);

    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == QUANTITY*(currentPage-1))
        {
            if(pagesLeft == true && !(loadingMore))
            {
                Log.w("DV", "Loading more");
                loadingMore = true;
                mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Patientez...", "Chargement des Favoris.", true);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

                new WebServiceWork().execute(this.profil_array);
            }
            else
            {
                if(pagesLeft == false)
                    Log.w("Favoris", "No pages left.");

                if(loadingMore)
                    Log.w("Favoris", "Loading more");

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){}


    private class WebServiceWork extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Profil>, Void, ArrayList<Profil>>
    {
        //ArrayList<String> profil_string_array;
        boolean pagesLeft;

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            loadingMore = true;
        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Profil> doInBackground(ArrayList<Profil>... profil_arrays)
        {
            WebService ws;
            int oldSize = profil_arrays[0].size();



            /* ... */


            //profil_arrays[0].addAll(ws.getProfilList());

                    /* getProfilList() return an ArrayList<Profil> */
            profil_arrays[0] = ws.getProfilList();

            pagesLeft = ws.pagesLeft();

            return profil_arrays[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Profil> profil_arrays)
        {
            EcranFavoris.this.profil_array = profil_arrays;
            EcranFavoris.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            EcranFavoris.this.mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            EcranFavoris.this.loadingMore = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
    {
        if(id != EcranFavoris.currentId)
        {
            currentPage = 1;
            EcranFavoris.currentId = id;
            this.pagesLeft = true;
            //profil_array = new ArrayList<Profil>();
            new WebServiceWork().execute(profil_array);
        }

        Log.w("DebugFavs","the item: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos) + "has been selected. id = " + Long.toString(id));

        ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        ((TextView)view).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 4);

    }

   /* ... */

}
```

EDIT: here's the adapter.
I didn't post the function setListInfo() because it's just basic TextView and Image view setting.

2ND EDIT: Tried using the ViewHolders, but my list doesn't show, and there no errors in Logcat.

```java
public class FavorisListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private static final int TYPE_MEMBRE = 0;
private static final int TYPE_PUB = 1;

/* La structure utilisée est une liste de "Profil", type que j'ai creer. */
private List<Profil> p_list;

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private static int nbrPub = 0;


public FavorisListAdapter(Context context, List<Profil> profil_list)
{
    this.context = context;
    p_list = profil_list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if(position % 4 == 0)
        return TYPE_PUB;
    return TYPE_MEMBRE;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return p_list.size();
}

public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 2;
}

public Object getItem(int pos)
{
    return p_list.get(pos);
}

public long getItemId(int pos)
{
    return pos;
}

static class PubViewHolder
{
    WebView pub;

    public void init(RelativeLayout layoutItem)
    {
        pub = (WebView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.visites_webView);
    }
}

static class MembreViewHolder
{
    TextView first_name;
    TextView age;
    TextView online;
    TextView lastVisit;

    ImageView image;

    public void init(RelativeLayout layoutItem)
    {
        first_name = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.visites_nameAge);
        age = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.visites_cityDistance);
        online = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.visites_online);
        lastVisit = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.visites_lastVisite);

        image = (ImageView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.visites_image);

    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
  RelativeLayout layoutItem = null;
  View v = convertView;
  int type = getItemViewType(position);

  MembreViewHolder membreHolder;
  PubViewHolder pubHolder;

  if(v == null)
  {
      switch(type)
      {
        case TYPE_MEMBRE:
            layoutItem = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.visites_list_row_layout, parent, false);
            membreHolder = new MembreViewHolder();
            membreHolder.init(layoutItem);
            v.setTag(membreHolder);
            this.setListInfo(membreHolder, position);
            break;

        case TYPE_PUB:
            layoutItem = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.visites_list_pub_layout, parent, false);
            pubHolder = new PubViewHolder();
            pubHolder.init(layoutItem);
            v.setTag(pubHolder);
            this.setListInfo(pubHolder, position);
            break;

      }
  }
  else
  {
      switch(type)
      {
        case TYPE_MEMBRE:
            membreHolder = (MembreViewHolder)v.getTag();
            this.setListInfo(membreHolder, position);
            break;

        case TYPE_PUB:
            pubHolder = (PubViewHolder)v.getTag();
            this.setListInfo(pubHolder, position);
      }
  }

  return layoutItem;
}


private void setListInfo(PubViewHolder p, int position)
{
    p.pub.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


}

private void setListInfo(MembreViewHolder m, int position)
{

    m.first_name.setText(p_list.get(position).getChamp("first_name") + ", " + p_list.get(position).getChamp("age") + " ans");
    m.age.setText(p_list.get(position).getChamp("city"));


    if(p_list.get(position).getChamp("online").equals("Oui"))
    {
        m.online.setText("En ligne");
        m.online.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        m.online.setText("Hors ligne");
        m.online.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    String last_visit = p_list.get(position).getChamp("visit_date");
    String formatted = last_visit.substring(6, 8) + "/" + last_visit.substring(4, 6) + "/"
            + last_visit.substring(0, 4);

    m.lastVisit.setText(formatted);


}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code of your custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

1. Never use the strings you display in the code like that : `ProgressDialog.show(this, "Patientez...", "Chargement des Favoris.", true);`. Please use  `ProgressDialog.show(this, EcranFavoris.this.getString(R.string.title), EcranFavoris.this.getString(R.string.message), true);` instead, everywhere you need to display a string (not in the logcat, it doesn't matter). 
   This let you to do multilingual applications easily.
2. I'm not sure but I think you don't use ViewHolders in your adapter. You should look at this and use it (optimisation point). There is a lot of tuts on google.
3. You should show your dialog in the `preExecute` method of your asyncTask and dismiss it on the `postExecute` method.
4. I think you should save your data not in JSON but as objects in your database. It will take more time when initializing but you can make cursors, etc.

Comment: Ok, so I know about 1), just forgot to do this one.

Comment: For 2) i'll do some research about it, never use it before
and for number 3) I tried doing this, I get the folowing message:
The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (EcranFavoris.WebServiceWork, String, String, boolean)

Comment: @user1486070 This is probably because you're in a inner class. Use this:  ProgressDialog.show(EcranFavoris.this, ...); I also added a 4)

Comment: Yep I'll try that. 4) good idea but the API i'm using for my work only send bqck JSON, XML or txt.
I've got a problem with the new adapter, so i'm going to edit the first post.

Comment: @user1486070 What's the pb, implement a MapperFactory for JSON, XML and txt. then save your objects in your db  and you'll use your db the same way anywhere. Not sure I'm clear

Comment: The problem: Tried using the ViewHolders, but my list doesn't show, and there no errors in Logcat.
I don't have access to the database, just have an API I use to get information.

Comment: @user1486070 The db can be usefull if you want to access your data offline. If you don't want, indeed, you don't need that :p

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Any ideas why my list doesn't work ? (I edited the first post)

Comment: @user1486070 I'll take a look when I have time

Comment: @user1486070 Do you have in your p_list members AND pubs? otherwise I think you 'll have troubles with your position. Anyway you should have errors in the logcat if not. Please make sure your list is not empty (by debugging or log)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. First, the problem is not coming from the adapter but from the code, and more precisely the AsyncTask. Got it working finaly, I'll post the proper code later and hope it helps someone.
CFlex thanks alot for your help and your comments :)